# How can I optimise an Update on a large table?

Tags: oracle, update, oracle-11g

I am using Oracle 11g, I have to update 7 fields on a table with 14 millions of rows, the updated columns get the new value from functions, the update looks like:

```
update hslak
set HSLAKSTS =  reverseheb(hslaksts) , 
HSLAKSBSTS=reversehebchars(hslaksbsts), 
HSLAKIVTK=reverseheb(HSLAKIVTK), 
HSLAKMKOR=reverseheb(HSLAKMKOR), 
HSLAKIRGTG=reverseheb(HSLAKIRGTG), 
HSLAKMCR= reverseheb(HSLAKMCR),
HSLAKMASL=reverseheb(HSLAKMASL);
```

it run for 6-7 hours and it is not over yet.

Would it be faster to create a new table rather then update it? Would it be better to create a loop and update 100000 records each time and commit after each iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Is the process I/O bound (there is lots of disk activity) or CPU bound (which is possible if the functions are complex)? It is most likely the former and if so then if there are indexes covering those columns it is usually better to drop them before operations that update every row and recreate them afterwards (don't drop the PK and/or clustered index though). "Usually" is an important word here: check it out in a test environment to confirm for your data.

> Would it be faster to create a new table rather then update it?

Probably not, unless the new table is on physically separate media so reading from the old and writing to the new does not cause head-thrashing on the physical disks.

> Would it be better to create a loop and update 100000 records each time and commit after each iteration?

If you and your users can cope with the data being partially updated at any given time then this (probably with a smaller number of rows then 100,000) gives you the advantage of not blocking your application for other uses as you don't have an update lock on the entire table for the length of time it takes to update all the rows. I've not used postgres much but assuming it behaves similarly to MS SQL Server (in simple recovery mode) using smaller updates inside explicit transactions can greatly reduce the amount of log file growth but is unlikely to significantly affect overall run-time.

If running the update in batches and allowing normal operations to continue on the application then obviously you shouldn't follow the first recommendation to drop indexes at the start & recreate them at the end - those indexes are likely to be essential to reasonable performance of the application.

Comment: I dont have to worry about other users cause i am the only user doing this data migration.

Comment: This update use a lot of CPU as the functions are complicated and it use a lot of I/O as well  , this table has no index

Comment: yeah if you have exclusive use on this server due to migration, then yeah splitting it up in parallel and doing smaller "chunks" (as David suggest) might actually allow you to at least see/monitor the progress ...

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new table and inserting data there should be faster because `update` generates more data for redo logs than `insert`. Batch `insert` speed can be greatly improved by using `APPEND` hint with `NOLOGGING` table (you can find some details http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nologging_append.htm )  .

Submitting data in chunks seems as a reasonable idea to me because it allows you to do migration in steps, control redo (and archive) log size, pause and resume update as needed based on server load.

There are couple other things you can try to make the query run faster. 
First of all, you can try using `PARALLEL` hint . When full table scan and is involved and you have enough resources, it can be quite beneficial. Note, parallel execution is not a silver bullet, and may not efficient in all cases. Some details can be found here,   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database-performance/geist-parallel-execution-1-1872400.html ) .

Also, I'd double check the efficiency of the functions involved. Would it be possible to rewrite them the way to minimize number of calls ? I mean, for instance, `reverseheb` is called 6 times for each row which involves 6 context switches SQL/PLSQL .  Is it possible to rewrite the function so it can be called just once ?

In addition, starting with 11g release 1 Oracle allows functions to cache results (`RESULT_CACHE`) which may help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

i think its beter to divide your table to 140 parts by a code like this:
update hslak
set HSLAKSTS =  reverseheb(hslaksts) , 
HSLAKSBSTS=reversehebchars(hslaksbsts), 
HSLAKIVTK=reverseheb(HSLAKIVTK), 
HSLAKMKOR=reverseheb(HSLAKMKOR), 
HSLAKIRGTG=reverseheb(HSLAKIRGTG), 
HSLAKMCR= reverseheb(HSLAKMCR),
HSLAKMASL=reverseheb(HSLAKMASL);
where id<100000 and id >0

its the first part.you can use a for statement and do it for all 140 parts quickly.i did not do that before but i think it work.